# Generating document preview using client side script

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, angular, aspose

I am working on a solution where i need to generate preview in popup for (pdf,word,excel) .I have achieved same by converting all format using Aspose.Words and Aspose.Cells. Below is my code:

```
 public ActionResult PreviewDoc(string fileName)
    {

        string fileExtension = fileName.Substring(fileName.LastIndexOf(".") + 1);
        string pathSource = Server.MapPath("~/"+ fileName);
        MemoryStream streamToWrite = new MemoryStream();
        using (FileStream file = new FileStream(pathSource, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            byte[] bytes = new byte[file.Length];
            file.Read(bytes, 0, (int)file.Length);
            streamToWrite.Write(bytes, 0, (int)file.Length);
        }

        var previewStream = this.GetPdfStream(fileExtension, streamToWrite);
        // Load the document.

        // Convert the document to byte form.
        byte[] docBytes = previewStream.ToArray();

        // The bytes are now ready to be stored/transmitted.
        // Now reverse the steps to load the bytes back into a document object.
        MemoryStream inStream = new MemoryStream();
        inStream.Write(docBytes, 0, docBytes.Length);
        inStream.Position = 0;

        return new FileStreamResult(inStream, "application/pdf");
    }

    public MemoryStream GetPdfStream(string extension, MemoryStream streamToRead)
    {
        MemoryStream outStream = new MemoryStream();
        if (extension.Trim().ToLower() == "doc" || extension.Trim().ToLower() == "docx")
        {
            Aspose.Words.Document doc = new Aspose.Words.Document(streamToRead);
            // Save the document to stream.
            doc.Save(outStream, SaveFormat.Pdf);
        }
        else if (extension.Trim().ToLower() == "xls" || extension.Trim().ToLower() == "xlsx")
        {
            Aspose.Cells.Workbook workbook = new Aspose.Cells.Workbook(streamToRead);
            workbook.Save(outStream, Aspose.Cells.SaveFormat.Pdf);
        }
        else
        {
            outStream = streamToRead;
        }

        return outStream;
    }
```

But as Aspose requires licesnse which i don't have so do we have any client side approach where we return stream from mvc controller and convert that to preview at client side and open in new window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is true that a valid license is a must to achieve the task. You can convert and send the output stream to client browser but it will contain the Aspose watermark. Furthermore you can get a temporary license for evaluation. Please visit the [link](http://www.aspose.com/corporate/purchase/temporary-license.aspx) and get the temporary license for 30 days.

I work with Aspose as Developer evangelist.